# Correct order on initial Raspbian setup/update after initial hardware setup?

Tags: setup, update, raspi-config

I download the Raspbian image, write it to the SD card, plug the SD into the Pi, connect it to router, plug in the power adapter. I connect via SSH.

In what order do I have to run the following tools? Does the order even matter? Can a wrong order screw anything up (well, on a fresh system I can just rewrite the SD card)?

```
raspi-config
rpi-update
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a sensible order.

raspi-config should give you the option to expand the ext4 partition to use all the unused SD card space.  You might need the extra space during the apt-get upgrade.

I'd be tempted to do the rpi-update last, as it might need certificates downloaded during the apt-get upgrade.